# Maven plugin for Tomcat 10

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-3

I'm trying to  update my plugin  in my new Maven project   as follows

```
  <!-- Tomcat Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat10-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <path>/foundraising</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but the error comes out

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:pom:10.1.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I am using  maven 3.8.1
IntellijIDEa 2023.1.2

Thank for the help

Comment: There is no plugin with this version as the error message implies... neither `tomcat10...` nor the related version `10.X`...  Why do you need a tomcat plugin ?

Comment: I just wanted to update it, thank you

Comment: I got this error while rining my project                                                               :SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/Arootiana.DESKTOP-846VCQN/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar!/] for annotations        and I refer to this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463294/i-am-getting-this-error-severe-unable-to-process-jar-entry-module-info-class#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20you%20probably%20need%20to%20upgrade%20your,for%20the%20specific%20versions%20that%20fix%20the%20problem.

Comment: This build using the tomcat-maven-plugin in that version can simple not work because that version does **NOT** exist... that's it... so there is no way to update it... Reconsider the reason to use that plugin...

Comment: Maybe an alternative would be the cargo-maven-plugin https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven+3+Plugin+Getting+Started.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such `tomcat10-maven-plugin` exists at the official repositories (perhaps your company has its own private repository where such a proprietary dependency might be available.

Based on the official Tomcat Maven Plugin [Github](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin) repository, there are two Maven modules corresponding each to a separate artifact:

- [`tomcat7-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/tree/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- [`tomcat8-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/tree/trunk/tomcat8-maven-plugin): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-r1756463</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

There is nothing such as a `tomcat9-maven-plugin` or `tomcat10-maven-plugin`, yet.

On the other hand, there is an issue discussing support for Tomcat 9: [#30](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/pull/30).

Comment: The referenced git repository is not updated for 4 years which I define as dead also the other references are out of date as well (tomcat7 2013 and tomcat8 2017!)...

Comment: The project is dead, the dependencies are alive.